# How to pass json data to collapsableheader tableview controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying many times but it does not work.

Error:

> /Users/admin/Desktop/Bkk 2/bkk/OfferDetailViewController.swift:93:55: Cannot convert value of type '[Deal]' to expected argument type '[String]'

Code:

```
var deals = [Deal]()

var sections = [Section]()


 sections = [
        Section(name: "Select from option", items:deals),
        Section(name: "merchant Details", items: [ForyouString, "iPad Air 2", "iPad mini 4", "Accessories"]),
        Section(name: "How to use deals", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"]),
        Section(name: "things to remember", items: ["exchange for cash not allowed"]),
        Section(name: "Cancelation policy", items: ["Once bought cannot exchange"]),
        Section(name: "what you get", items: ["Capacity buliding courses"])
    ]
 func parseDeals(data: NSData) -> [Deal]{
    var deals = [Deal]()

    do{
        let jsonresult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        let jsondeals = jsonresult?["deals"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsondeal in jsondeals{
            let deal = Deal()
            deal.deals_name = jsondeal["deals_name"] as! String
            deal.image_url = jsondeal["image_url"] as! String
            deal.actual_price = jsondeal["actual_price"] as! String
            deal.discounted_price = jsondeal["discounted_price"] as! String
            deal.discounted_percentage = jsondeal["discounted_percentage"] as! String
            deal.max_purchase_per_customer = jsondeal["max_purchase_per_customer"] as! String
            deal.qty_available = jsondeal["qty_available"] as! String
            deal.valid_from = jsondeal["valid_from"] as! String
            deal.valid_to = jsondeal["valid_to"] as! String
            deals.append(deal)

        }
                }
    catch{
        print(error)

    }
    return deals
}


func back(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func buttonClicked(){

    print("button Clicked")

}
func showLocalError(errorMsg: String,title:String = "Oops!") {
    let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
        showCloseButton: true
    )
    let alertView = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
    alertView.showWarning(title, subTitle: errorMsg)
}


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].items.count
}

// 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell? ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].collapsed! ? 0 : 44.0
}
```

It shows error at sections, when I pass deals in that it shows error, I cannot find where I did mistake, I need how to pass deals array in sections.

Comment: You seems to use Swift 3, avoid using So avoid `NSDictionary`, and other "too Objective-C" stuff.

Comment: `cell.textLabel?.text = sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]` In case of `section == 0`, then you have a array of Deals objects, not an array of Strings.

Comment: it shows error at   sections = [
        Section(name: "Select from option", items:deals), when i pass deals here it shows that error

Comment: Not related but what is the deep sense to assign / cast `.mutableContainers` to an immutable object?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear:

In the line

```
Section(name: "Select from option", items:deals)
```

you are passing an array of `Deal` objects as the second parameter instead of an expected array of `String`, the `Section` initializer is

```
init(name: String, items: [String])
```

Comment: even it shows error   /Users/admin/Desktop/B 2/By/OfferDetailViewController.swift:93:56: Cannot convert value of type '[String].Type' (aka 'Array<String>.Type') to expected argument type '[String]'

Comment: How did you change the line? I suspect you wrote `Section(name: "Select from option", items:[String])` which is wrong. You have to pass an array of strings like in the other lines or you pass an empty array then write `Section(name: "Select from option", items:[String]())`

Comment: sections = [
            Section.init(name: "SelectFromOptions", items: [String])

Comment: but my deals array data not going there

Comment: No, the types don't match, hence the error message.

Comment: As @vadian says, you're passing `deals` as a parameter for your `Section` init, and you've created `deals` as a `Deal` array in the first line of your code: `var deals = [Deal]()`

Comment: @Matt  can we send deals data in sections

Comment: You can but you need an appropriate initializer which takes `[Deal]` as a parameter. It's like you cannot insert an USB connector in a FireWire jack.